# How can I prevent redis from crashing the entire application on connection error?

Tags: redis

I'm using the redis npm package in a TypeScript Node.js app. If redis fails to connect, it takes my app down with it regardless of how many try-catch blocks I use. Modifying the `client.on("error"...` hook doesn't have an effect.

The following code (from 2016) is supposed to solve the issue:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function (options) {
    if (options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
      // This will suppress the ECONNREFUSED unhandled exception
      // that results in app crash
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

However I get a TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '{ retry_strategy: (options: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts>'.
```

Even if I add @ts-ignore, the solution above has no effect.

Another way to solve this is to use ioredis, but I want to use the redis package. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an error (such as a network error), the client will emit an `error` event (which you'll have to handle, otherwise the process will crash. see [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/2302)) -> call `reconnectStrategy` (which in most cases you shouldn't override, the default one will retry with a backoff between 0-500ms, depends of the number of retries) to decide if it needs to reconnect, and the backoff strategy -> reconnect to the server -> keep processing the commands in the queue.
You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#what-happens-when-the-network-goes-down) and [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md#reconnect-strategy).

Comment: disconnecting on error & using the disableOfflineQueue option seems to be the right solution

Comment: If you call `.disconnect()` on error the client won't reconnect and you won't be able to use it until you restart the app or call `.connect()` again

Comment: Calling `.connect()` in a try-catch block in each service function that uses redis seems to be the way to go then. I can then just ping redis to see if it's connected. Not sure if there's a more elegant way to handle this (the app doesn't strictly need redis to run).

Comment: If the app does not strictly need Redis to run, instead of `await`ing `client.connect()` you can call it and just ignore the `then` (or add a console log or something if you wish to..), and add `.catch` just in case one day you'll change the `retryStrategy` (which by default will keep retry forever)

Answer (score 0):

So far the only working solution (that doesn't rely on other libraries) seems to be to disconnect when encountering an error:

```
client.on("error", (e) => {
  // handle error
  client.disconnect();
});
```